# Patching with Retrofit - ID property only

Tags: android, json, orm, retrofit

I am making use of Retrofit in my app, it manages API calls well and supports GET and PATCH as I require.

Given the following JSON:

```
"fruit_set": [
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "fruit": {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Apple", 
            "desc": ""
        }, 
        "source": 2, 
        "inventory": 8.0
    }, 
    {
        "id": 6, 
        "fruit": {
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Mango", 
            "desc": "delicious"
        }, 
        "source": 2, 
        "inventory": 15.0
    }]
```

Ignoring names for a minute.

I have setup a PoJo for both FruitSet and Fruit with the required getters/setters. FruitSet.Fruit is defined as List and is populated nicely with a GET call. My problem is with PATCH.

Fruit in this instance is reference data therefore I only need to insert the Fruit.id when assigning it to my FruitSet PoJo.

Can I instruct Retrofit that it doesn't need to write Fruit but only the Fruit.id to the database table. I was hoping Retrofit was smart enough to do that?

Basically I want this JSON structure when I PATCH:

```
    "fruit_set": [
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "fruit": 1, 
        "source": 2, 
        "inventory": 8.0
    }, 
    {
        "id": 6, 
        "fruit": 2, 
        "source": 2, 
        "inventory": 15.0
    }]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can fetch anything you want via parsing.. show me your code where you're parsing.

Comment: Fetching is fine, I am able to retrieve the data no problems. The issue I am finding occurs when I want to PATCH an object. (I have edited my question to illustrate the JSON I would like to PATCH with)

Comment: Retrofit doesn't do any of that. You'll have to make a post request and in that request send the data the way you want.

Comment: It will do PATCH when used with the OkHttp library so I can execute a PATCH no problems.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking I implemented a custom Gson serializer that outputs only the ID instead of the entire Fruit object. This article really helped, especially towards the bottom:

http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/